# MUI datagrid : how to disable multi-filtering on selected columns

Tags: filter, material-ui, datagrid

In my project, the filtering function is running server-side, and our service does not provide multiple filters for the same column. So, I want to prevent the MUI `Datagrid-pro` multiple filters on a selected column. I tried to override columnInputProps of filterPanel, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to deactivate or hide an already selected column in the column option of the next filter?

Description Image here!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Set 'disableMultipleColumnsFiltering' to true

```
<DataGridPro disableMultipleColumnsFiltering='true'> </DataGridPro>
```

Reference: https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33055578)

Comment: Thanks for your review, just add a sample code here